# find row number for matching value and store in variable

Tags: excel, match, row, vba

Based on an input value I want to find the cell in a table, and store the row number in a variable. This variable will be used to multiply the corresponding values in the next columns with the input number. My code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Calculate()

Dim var As Variant
Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim Mx As Variant
Dim Nx As Variant
Dim Ox As Variant
Dim Px As Variant
Dim Qx As Variant
Dim Rx As Variant
Dim low As Variant
Dim cat As Variant

rownumber = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value, Sheets("C-type").Range("L5:L345"), 0)


Mx = Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value * Sheets("C-type").Range("M" & rownumber).Value
Nx = Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value * Sheets("C-type").Range("N" & rownumber).Value
Ox = Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value * Sheets("C-type").Range("O" & rownumber).Value
Px = Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value * Sheets("C-type").Range("P" & rownumber).Value
Qx = Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value * Sheets("C-type").Range("Q" & rownumber).Value
Rx = Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value * Sheets("C-type").Range("R" & rownumber).Value

cat = Array(Mx, Nx, Ox, Px, Qx, Rx)

low = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(cat)

Sheets("User Interface").Range("C45").Value = low

Sheets("User Interface").Range("c45").Activate
Application.Goto ActiveCell.EntireRow, True

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get subscript out of range-error on my match function, thus I'm starting to doubt that this is the correct way to go about it. I need to somehow be able to reference the row number of the matching number in the table, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would the `.Find()` function work? Something like `rownumber = Sheets("User Interface").Range("L5:L345").Find(What:=Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row` maybe?

Comment: You could also try some form of error catching. You might be getting Error 9 because there isn't a match, or your match is #N/A. Try using `Application.Match` and follow that with an `If IsError(rownumber) = False Then your code Else MsgBox("Value not found.") End If`. When `WorksheetFunction.MATCH` can't find a value, it will throw Runtime Error 9. `Application.MATCH` will also throw an error, but the error will be assigned to `rownumber` which you can trap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
    strToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("User Interface").Range("K27").Value
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C-type").Range("L5:L345")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, strToFind) > 0 Then
        Set Rng1 = Rng.Find(strToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                rownumber = Rng1.Row
        Else
            MsgBox strToFind & " does not exist in range " & Rng.Address
    End If
```

Comment: Hello Maddy and thanks for your suggestion. I tried to implement this: dim'ed strToFind as variant and Rng, Rng1 as range then variant. In both cases I'm still getting the "subscript out of range"-error on my find-range. Ie the 'Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C-type").Range("L5:L345")' line. Any suggestions for how to try troubleshooting?

Comment: Maddy thank you! The issue was actually the hyphen in the name "C-type". Changed it to Ctype, now it works.